# Error in reading the pdf file while using langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, pypdf, langchain

```
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
loader = PyPDFLoader(input_datapath)
pages = loader.load_and_split()
```

```
error in reading data file -Stream has ended unexpectedly
EOF marker not found
invalid pdf header: b'<!doc'
```

However works fine when done locally, error is when executed via GCP function.
Even similar library version is used.
Any pointers on how to solve ?